# JSON data - How to parse?

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-json

Suppose I have data in JSON. How can I parse the data so I can get the values of nested objects (e.g. `kind`, `id` and `title`)?

My JSON data is:

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "UExkc1JWcGJNV19LSH",
      "items":[
        {
          "title": "New Updates",
        }
      ],
  }],
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you should remove all the commas since last items should not be followed by one.

So more like:

```
{
    "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
    "items": [{
        "id": "UExkc1JWcGJNV19LSH",
        "items": [{
            "title": "New Updates"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Other than that you can just use JSONObject lib and extract the value you need. For example to get the kind:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(strInput);
String kind = jsonObj.getString("kind"); // kind now contains "youtube#playlistItemListResponse"
```

where strInput is the above json as a string.

More info: https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject

Comment: Thnx alot sir. Its the finalize answer for my this question. Thanks for your precious comment